# how to add € (euro symbol) in syabse table record

Tags: sybase

I am trying to insert euro symbol in a sybase table

```
insert into ABC(viewId,viewType,business) values(16014,'Legal Entity','NV (€)');
```

But instead of eurosymbol i get -> symbol on insertion.
I need a euro symbol in my table. How can i do so?

Comment: Are you working with PHP?

Comment: no... I was unable to solve this one as my syabse db had charset as iso_1 so I chose to change the requirement and go with "euro" and not it's symbol for simplicity.

Comment: Did you try to change the collection of your tb to latin1_german2_ci or latin1_swedish_ci ? The € symbol is available is this collections.

Comment: no. had to deliver it asap so disucssed the user to change the requirement

Answer (score 0):

What makes you say you don't have a Euro symbol in your table? 
Could it be that the client app with which you display the data is not properly converting the character set?